# How to apply d3.js svg clipping after zooming

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to use an svg-clippath with d3.js and the zoom behaviour.
The following code creates a rectangle, which will then be clipped by a rectangualar clipping region.

```
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script>

var width = 800;
var height = 600;

var svg = d3.select(".chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");

var clip = svg.append("defs")
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id","clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width",200)
    .attr("height",200)
    .attr("x",100)
    .attr("y",100);


var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().
    on("zoom",zoomed);

function zoomed(){
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate
    +")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    container.attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");
}

    svg.call(zoom);

var container = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");

var rect = container.append("rect")
    //.attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .attr("x",150)
    .attr("y",150)
    .attr("width",350)
    .attr("height",350);

</script>
```

What I want is for the clipping to be applied again after zooming / moving (so that I cannot 
move the rectangle outh of the clipping region, which right now i can do without any problems.) How do I do that?

I am assuming that the current behaviour is caused by the fact that the clipping is applied before the transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out a solution. Apparently, the clip-path operates on the object **prior** to transformation. So I tried to **reverse-transform the clip object** when performing the zoom transformation, and this worked !

It is something in the spirit of:

```
var clip_orig_x = 100, clip_orig_y = 100;
function zoomed() {
    var t = d3.event.translate;
    var s = d3.event.scale;

    // standard zoom transformation:
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + t +")scale(" + s + ")"); 

    // the trick: reverse transform the clip object!
    clip.attr("transform", "scale(" + 1/s + ")")
        .attr("x", clip_orig_x - t[0]) 
        .attr("y", clip_orig_y - t[1]);
}
```

where clip is the rectangle in the clipPath. Because of interactions between zooming and translation, you need to set "x" and "y" explicitly instead of using transform.

I am sure experienced d3 programmers out there will come up with a better solution, but this works !

Comment: In my previous answer, I had forgotten to indicate the clip rectangle origin (assuming 0, 0) so it would be off by 100, 100.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was suspecting. Thanks for confirming. Reverse-transforming fixes the problem.